# nonlinear regression with time series error

Tags: r, time-series, residuals, nonlinear-regression, stationarity

I have a question about data analysis. I fitted my data to non linear regression by using `nls` function in R. Then I plot the residuals. The  residuals are non stationary but when I plot `diff(residual)` they become stationary.

Is it correct to use `diff(residual)` to transform non-stationary to stationary?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question!

`diff()` function in R takes the differences with lag=1 by default (unless specified otherwise).

In your case, it is correct to use the `diff(residuals)` command to detrend the data. 
However, in order to say that it’s stationary, you will need to test for it. Taking first differences doesn’t necessarily mean that the process will be stationary.

If you want to test for stationarity, my most used method is working with `aTSA` package.

`diff_res<-diff(residuals)`

`library(aTSA)`

`stationary.test(diff_res, method = adf)`

The function will return `TRUE` if the process is stationary and `FALSE` if the process is not stationary.

Comment: Technically Augmented DIckey-Fuller's alternative hypothesis is **does not have unit root**. While that includes truly stationary data, it also includes auto-regressive data that could have memory processes long enough to not get to a stable equilibrium within the observed span of the time series.